# How to add Attributes to a polygon with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, polygon, cursor

I have a question about arcpy. I want to create a polygon FeatureClass with attributes. The code below is just test-code that generates some polygons for speed testing. I want to add some additional attributes like ID (integer) and Material-Type (string) to each polygon. I know that this is possible with the insert.cursor function. But I want to do it with the *CopyFeatures* function, because this is faster (I have to generate some 100'000 thousand's polygon).

```
import arcpy
import time

# Variablen definieren
workspace = "E:/GeschiebeGIS/Python/Sandkasten/CreatePolygon"
shapeCursor = "polygonCursor.shp"
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4149) # Spatial reference GCS_CH1903

# Zeitmessung starten
startTime = time.clock()

# shape Datei löschen
arcpy.Delete_management(workspace+"/"+shapeCursor)

# shape Datei erstellen
#arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(workspace, shapeCursor, "POLYGON", "", "DISABLED", "DISABLED")

# feature List erstellen
featureList = []

# leeres Array erstellen
array = arcpy.Array()

# 100 Testpolygone erstellen
for c1 in range (0, 100):
    point1 = arcpy.Point(c1,c1)
    point2 = arcpy.Point(c1+1,c1)
    point3 = arcpy.Point(c1+1,c1+1)
    point4 = arcpy.Point(c1,c1+1)
    point5 = arcpy.Point(c1,c1)
    array.add(point1)
    array.add(point2)
    array.add(point3)
    array.add(point4)
    array.add(point5)
    polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)
    array.removeAll()
    featureList.append(polygon)

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(featureList, workspace+"/"+shapeCursor)

print "Fettich"
print time.clock() - startTime, "seconds"
```

is it possible to add the attributes to the polygon object in the For loop?

Answer (score 7):

If you have ArcGIS 10.1 or higher then a Data Access Insert cursor is faster than CopyFeatures_management by more than double the speed.  I ran your test code and it took over 22 seconds to run.  I rewrote it to use a da InsertCursor and it took less than 8.233 seconds to run.

The da insert cursor can handle all of the attributes you want as well.  After adding the code to create the two fields and fill them with values the script still took less than 8.381 seconds to run.

Virtually all of the time was used to do the imports of arcpy and time and to create the feature class and add the fields.  The Insert Cursor portion of the script took less than 0.427 seconds to run.  So in reality, CopyFeatures_Management takes about 14 seconds to run and the Data Access Insert Cursor is more than 32 times faster.

Also, a shapefile can only store 2GB in any of its files.  It is not really designed for large files and its performance will totally suck for the final number of records you want to generate.  If you really plan on generating a huge number of polygons, forget using a shapefile and go to a file geodatabase.  An fgdb can store over 4 billion records per feature class and by default the whole fgdb can grow to be 1 TB in total size with an option to go up to 256 TB for the entire fgdb.  fgdb performance is just fine for feature classes with 1 million records plus.

Here is the script I ran:

```
import arcpy
import time

# Variablen definieren
workspace = "E:/GeschiebeGIS/Python/Sandkasten/CreatePolygon"
shapeCursor = "polygonCursor.shp"
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4149) # Spatial reference GCS_CH1903

# Zeitmessung starten
startTime = time.clock()

# shape Datei löschen
arcpy.Delete_management(workspace+"/"+shapeCursor)

# shape Datei erstellen
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(workspace, shapeCursor, "POLYGON", "", "DISABLED", "DISABLED")

# Add Fields
arcpy.AddField_management(shapeCursor, "ID", "LONG", "", "", "", "ID", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED")

arcpy.AddField_management(shapeCursor, "MATERIAL_T", "TEXT", "", "", 50, "MATERIAL_TYPE", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED")

# feature List erstellen
#featureList = []

# leeres Array erstellen
array = arcpy.Array()

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(shapeCursor, ["ID", "MATERIAL_T", "SHAPE@"])

# 100 Testpolygone erstellen
for c1 in range (0, 100):
    point1 = arcpy.Point(c1,c1)
    point2 = arcpy.Point(c1+1,c1)
    point3 = arcpy.Point(c1+1,c1+1)
    point4 = arcpy.Point(c1,c1+1)
    point5 = arcpy.Point(c1,c1)
    array.add(point1)
    array.add(point2)
    array.add(point3)
    array.add(point4)
    array.add(point5)
    polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)
    array.removeAll()
#    featureList.append(polygon)
    cursor.insertRow([c1, "Gold", polygon])

del cursor

#arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(featureList, workspace+"/"+shapeCursor)

print "Fettich"
print time.clock() - startTime, "seconds"
```