# ArcPy Table to Table Conversion Not Working Correctly

Tags: python, arcpy, json

I have a script which writes the lat/lng of a JSON web service of bus routes.  The script writes the latitude and longitude to a CSV correctly.  However my table to table conversion does not work correctly in Python.

```
# IMPORTS

#Make Python understand how to read things on the Internet
import urllib2

#Make Python understand the stuff in a page on the Internet is JSON
import json
from decimal import Decimal

# Make Python understand csvs
import csv

# Make Python know how to take a break so we don't hammer API and exceed rate limit
from time import sleep

# tell computer where to put CSV
outfile_path='C:\Users\Administrator\PycharmProjects\untitled\json2fgdb.csv'

# open it up, the w means we will write to it
writer = csv.writer(open(outfile_path, 'wb'))

#create a list with headings for our columns
headers = ['latitude', 'longitude']

#write the row of headings to our CSV file
writer.writerow(headers)


# GET JSON AND PARSE IT INTO DICTIONARY

# We need a loop because we have to do this for every JSON file we grab

#set a counter telling us how many times we've gone through the loop, this is the first time, so we'll set it at 1
i=1

#loop through pages of JSON returned, 100 is an arbitrary number
while i<2:
    #print out what number loop we are on, which will make it easier to track down problems when they appear
    print i
    #create the URL of the JSON file we want. We search for 'egypt', want English tweets,
#and set the number of tweets per JSON file to the max of 100, so we have to do as little looping as possible
    url = urllib2.Request('http://api.metro.net/agencies/lametro/routes/704/vehicles/' + str(i))
    #use the JSON library to turn this file into a Pythonic data structure
    parsed_json = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://api.metro.net/agencies/lametro/routes/704/vehicles/'))
    #now you have a giant dictionary.
#Type in parsed_json here to get a better look at this.
#You'll see the bulk of the content is contained inside the value that goes with the key, or label "results".
#Refer to results as an index. Just like list[1] refers to the second item in a list,
#dict['results'] refers to values associated with the key 'results'.
    print parsed_json



    #run through each item in results, and jump to an item in that dictionary, ex: the text of the tweet
    for items in parsed_json['items']:

     #initialize the row
         row = []
     #add every 'cell' to the row list, identifying the item just like an index in a list

    row.append(str(items['longitude']).encode('utf-8'))
    row.append(str(items['latitude']).encode('utf-8'))

     #once you have all the cells in there, write the row to your csv
    writer.writerow(row)
    #increment our loop counter, now we're on the next time through the loop
    i = i +1
    #tell Python to rest for 5 secs, so we don't exceed our rate limit
    #sleep(5)




    import arcpy
    arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(outfile_path, "C:\dev_folder\orginalDev.gdb", "jsoncsv2")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: If you need to get the data into file geodatabase, why not just use a DA cursor to write the rows directly to a table?  You can even populate the geometry during write instead of being dependent on an event theme.

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Comment: GSE is *filled* with data access cursor examples.  Searching GSE on "arcgis insert da cursor" returned [A: How to add Attributes to a polygon with arcpy](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127586/how-to-add-attributes-to-a-polygon-with-arcpy/127596#127596) which demonstrates polygon creation.  You can create a new question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't close the stream and flush the buffer to disk. No problem with Arcpy part. Just change you code like this:

```
#open it up, the w means we will write to it
f = open(outfile_path, 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(f)

...

f.close()

import arcpy
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(outfile_path, "C:\dev_folder\orginalDev.gdb", "jsoncsv2")
```

Comment: This worked a charm.

Comment: If you found the answer correct, please mark is as correct answer. Thanks